# How do I properly backreference this regex pattern?

Tags: regex, backreference

I have this regex
`(?<={|\sand\s)(.*?)(?=\sand\s)`

which matches only "one", "two", and "three"
`{one and two and three and four}`

but when I try to backreference `\sand\s` with `\1`

`(?<={|(\sand\s)\1)(.*?)(?=\1)`

It does not match "one", only "two" and "three"

I just started regex so i'm not sure what is happening here, help would be appreciated

EDIT: I apologize, it seems I did not understand what backreferencing meant at first, I realize it is not required for my case, thank you however for those who took the time to understand this nonsense.

Comment: What are you trying to match using your second pattern?

Comment: Please show the given string and the desired result, and give the rule (in words, not the regex) that you wish to apply that produces the desired result. What is the point of the back-referencing a literal (`" and "`)? I suggest you focus less on the technique (back-referencing) and simply explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, i was simply wondering why applying backreferencing to `\sand\s` gave a different result than when I was not backreferencing
`{one and two and three and four}`
desired result 'one', 'two' and 'three'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to match are the number words, then this seems to work (albeit without backreference):

```
"(?<=\{|\sand\s)(.*?)(?=\}|\sand\s)"
```